# eclipse aspectj nature : maven webapp project not compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj, m2e, aspectj-maven-plugin

I want to start using aspectj for my webapp project with maven in eclipse. My first step was adding the AspectJ nature. Before the I added the aspect the project was compiling fine, and I saw *.class files in the target/classed directory.

After adding the AspectJ nature the following marker appeared:

> Classpath Dependency Validator Message: Classpath entry
>   org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ASPECTJRT_CONTAINER will not be exported or
>   published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.

In the target/classes there were also no *.class files.

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to resolve this issue ?

Best regards,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

I have to **add AspectJ Maven plugin to you pom.xml**.
Here is more info: http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: I have tried that (and tried it again to make suree I missed nothing), not with no success. Note that also classes where no aspects needs to be weaved don't compile (and are giving ClassNotFoundException,e.g., for my web app context listener). Any other ideas ?

Comment: Can you post full stack trace?